# Matlab opticalFlow components to complex vector field

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, vision, opticalflow

I am trying to update legacy code that uses the no longer supported MATLAB call to

```
   opticalFlowClass = vision.OpticalFlow('OutputValue', ...
     'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form', 'Method', method);
```

which as the call indicates, outputs a M x N matrix in complex form.
The current call, for example

```
     opticalFlowClass = opticalFlowHS;
     flow = estimateFlow(opticalFlowClass, video);
```

outputs a flow object with the components

```
    flow.Vx
    flow.Vy
    flow.Magnitude
    flow.Orientation
```

Due to dependencies elsewhere in the code and to avoid a complete rewrite, I would like to use the components from the new call to form the matrix in the complex form of the old call. However, I was unable to find any documentation how the complex form was created. My question is

**What is the structure of the complex form and how was it created from the components and orientation?**

Any links to old documentation that explain this would be much appreciated.

Edit: I should add that I speculate that

```
    Flow = complex(Vx,Vy),
```

but I have no support for this

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the documentation exactly what that output option means. If you're interested you can access the legacy documentation at.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow-class.html

Diving through the undocumented `videooptflowlines` function it appears that `real(flow)` represents the horizontal velocity with positive right and `imag(flow)` represents the vertical velocity with positive down. So your speculation is correct

```
flowComplex = complex(flow.Vx, flow.Vy);
```